# Android: custom separator (or even item) in ListView depening on content of item

Tags: android, listview, separator

I've a ListView with items containing information about places with a **rating** and the **distance** to the current location.

The items are sorted into groups:

- Group 1: within 500m
- Group 2: 500m - 1km
- Group 3: 1km - 1.5km
- ...

Withing these groups the items are sorted by their rating.

Now I put out these items via my custom adapter (extension of `BaseAdapter`) into the `ListView`, which works perfectly.

However, what I'd like to do is to put a separator before the each first item of each group. This separator can be a `TextView` saying e.g. *500m - 1km* followed by all the `ListView` items in that group.

Any idea on how to realize this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Here is one implementation](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ListView/Sections/) that does exactly what you describe.

That one is GPLv3, because it is derived from [this implementation](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/), which was GPLv3.

You can also use my [`MergeAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) for this, which has the advantage of being Apache License 2.0. Just hand it an alternating set of header `TextView`s and `Adapter`s containing each section's worth of content.

Or, you can peek at all of these and roll their behaviors into your existing `Adapter` class. The trick is to return your `TextView` headers at the right spot, and properly implement methods like `getViewTypeCount()`, `getItemViewType()`, `areAllItemsEnabled()`, and `isEnabled()`.

Comment: Do you have any screen shots?

Comment: There is a screen shot of the first one in my Advanced Android book. There is a screen shot of the second one on Jeff Sharkey's site, as linked to above. I do not have a screen shot of the third one anyway, in large part because it would not be a screen shot of MergeAdapter, but a screen shot of whatever you poured into MergeAdapter.

Comment: Your implementation of SectionedAdapter works beautifully. Thanks! A quick question: Is there a way to remove the bottom divider from the last list item of each section?

Comment: @Jeffrey: Ummm...probably not easily. Those dividers are put there by Android, for all selectable items.

Comment: Here is another and I think easier solution for this http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/

Answer (score 4):

Here is even nicer implementation, inspired from iOS section list view : http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/. The nie thing about it is that the section header remains visible even if you scroll the section down.