# How to set up a real custom Listview?

Tags: android, listview

In my app, I should set up a "real" custom listview. 
For example :

---

First line(Some Text)               Checkbox

Second line(Some Text)              Spinner

---

What I mean is that each line has different widget. In the example, for the first line, we have a checkbox, for the second, it is a Spinner.

Does someone have any idea of how I can set it up?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Do you really think you need a `ListView`? Or could a `ScrollView` fix your problem already?
If you definitely need a ListView, read my answer here: [How to add multiple headers throughout a single ListView with addHeaderView()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730358/how-to-use-android-addheaderview/3765054#3765054)
You can define different types for your items and return a different layout for each type, while still having the possibility to get higher performance by using `convertView`.

Comment: And if it absolutely must be a ListView, check out Commonsware's SackOfViewsAdapter (http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-sacklist)

Answer (score 2):

Check out an example given on this page for defining custom-listview: http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-listview-tutorial-example/

Same way, you can define your custom-layout for listview, you just need to implement **getView** method.