# How to add Header to the listview which will move horizontally with the elements in the listview in android?

Tags: android, listview, header

My query is that how can i add Header to the listview which will be static vertically but horizontally it can move with the items in the listview.
for e.g. say i have 8 columns in listview i have used custom adapter extends Baseadapter to inflate the view now each column has header.
so i want this each header in listview. now suppose i move the list horizontally header also should move. and if i scroll vertically then header should not move vertically it should stick to its position. i have tried addHeaderView but my header moves vertical also.
you can think of how "microsoft excel" works if you scroll vertically than you will get thounds of rows whith static header but if you move horizontally the header also move along with the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try listView.addHeaderView()

The documentation for [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29) is available on developer.android.com

There are already a lot of other questions like this on, look at [how-to-use-android-addheaderview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730358/how-to-use-android-addheaderview) which may also be useful to you if you need additional information

Please use the search facility to look for more answers