# Android Section Header Custom Adapter

Tags: android

I am having my friends birthday's list extracted from the Facebook.

I populate the birthday date and Name in ListView..

I want the separator that having header for all month (i.e) January,Feb,March etc...

Persons having birthday in January month  should listed below the "January header" then person having birthday in Feb should listed below Feb Header..Similarly upto December..

I am having separator header  for Names of person by using "Alphabetic Section Indexer"
 similar i want to Separator for Month wise..

Check this Link, in these Alphabet is separator instead of that i want Months as Separator [Alphabetic Adapter](http://androidseverywhere.info/JAAB/)
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this
[Android: custom separator (or even item) in ListView depening on content of item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606320/android-custom-separator-or-even-item-in-listview-depening-on-content-of-item)

You can have group headers for non expandable lists also

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ExpandableListView.  You can have each Month as a Group and the date/name fields as the Child. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this View for spliting lists into sections with a custom spearator.
http://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/

[image: SectionListAdapter]