# Create a cursor adapter to display more items than in cursor itself

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: custom separator (or even item) in ListView depening on content of item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606320/android-custom-separator-or-even-item-in-listview-depening-on-content-of-item)

I've got a cursor from database query. Imagine it contains N items. Each of these items are of the same view type, but they differ in some cursor's field value (let's name it a data type).

I want to draw a list view with the following content (drawing a some "separator" before each of data type group).

```
--DataType1---------
Item1
Item2
--DataType2---------
Item3
--DataType3---------
Item4
Item5
```

The problem is what i have only 5 rows in cursor but need to draw 8 items in `ListView` (3 of one view type - a separator, and 5 of another view type).

Is there an ability to do this?

P.S. I know how to implement custom adapter, i know what `getItemViewType` and `getViewTypeCount` is for.

Comment: Not related to Cursors, but you may want to look at ExpandableListView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a duplicate, answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606320/android-custom-separator-or-even-item-in-listview-depening-on-content-of-item/1606642#1606642).

I also do something similar in my public domain [Dhammapada](https://github.com/appamatto/dhammapada-android) app, in [HeadingAdapter.java](https://github.com/appamatto/dhammapada-android/blob/master/src/com/appamatto/dhammapada/HeadingAdapter.java).

Comment: Yes, it is duplicate. Am i need to delete question or just leave my close vote here?

Comment: @Olegas I closed it as a dupe, no need to delete this question, your question is worded totally differently and may help future searchers