# Is it possible to add a special row in android search suggestions?

Tags: android, search, adapter

I added the Search Dialog (Quick Search Box) to my activity, which shows suggestions from my sqlite database. This works very well.

I would like to add a special row at the top of the suggestions ListView to offer the possibility to launch a remote search. For example, I would like to have a row "Search an address from Internet" which will open an other Activity.

Is there a day to do that ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to specialize your adapter
Here are some good pointers 
[Android: custom separator (or even item) in ListView depening on content of item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606320/android-custom-separator-or-even-item-in-listview-depening-on-content-of-item)

just have to return the first view as view you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use a custom adapter for search suggestions. It is done by the android search framework. How to change the base adapter for those suggestions ?

Comment: yep sorry didn't read as i should have. You are returning a cursor from your content provider ? then you can use a `MatrixCursor` instead,  so you can programmatically add a row to your result. Then add `SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA` column to identify in your activity which row as been selected. That should do it. more infos here : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html