# How can I add an ImageView as a ListView Header?

Tags: android, listview, header

Can anyone help me to find out how to add an ImageView as a header to a ListView?

My code is here:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View snapshot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_snapshot, null);

ListView channelsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.channelsList);
channelsList.addHeaderView(snapshot);
```

By now it shows nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try inflating your header view passing the parent (ListView) as parameter:

```
ListView channelsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.channelsList);
View snapshot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_snapshot, channelList, false);
```

Then, just add it to the ListView:

```
channelsList.addHeaderView(snapshot);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CommonsWare [MergeAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) or [SectionedListAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/ListView). With this library you can use any `View` as Header in your `Listview`. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606320/android-custom-separator-or-even-item-in-listview-depening-on-content-of-item) and accepted answer for more information.

Comment: @Downvoter Downvoting and not giving a reason does not help anyone. I want to know what i did wrong, i have used what i posted and it really helped me. I don't give answers without having tested them before.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ListView channelsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.channelsList);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_snapshot, channelsList , false);
channelsList .addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

Comment: Yep, specifying list as a parent while inflating helped!

Comment: I know, but my reputation here is too low to Upvote answers(( Really sorry

Answer (score 0):

In layout map_snapshot,you must be having parent layout as here i have taken Linear Layout likewise take that.

```
 ListView channelsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.channelsList);
    LinearLayout headerView = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_snapshot, null);
    listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

if you want to add views in layout:

```
TextView mUsername=(TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
```