# "Separator" in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I am showing data in listview from json using AsynTask.

Code is here.

```
public class MenuTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // Getting JSON String from URL..............
        JSONObject jsonObject = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                "http://smartaway.dk/json/submenu.php?resid=" + res_id,
                "POST", params);
        try {
            bestdeal = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_MENU);

            // / LOOping through AllEvents........
            for (int i = 0; i < bestdeal.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject e = bestdeal.getJSONObject(i);
                String resname = e.getString(TAG_MENUNAME);
                String city_state = e.getString(TAG_PRICE);

                // Creating New HAsh Map.........
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                // map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_MENUNAME, resname);
                map.put(TAG_PRICE, city_state);
                /*
                 * map.put(TAG_STREET, street); map.put(TAG_COUSINE,
                 * cousine); map.put(TAG_RES_LOGO, reslogo);
                 */
                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                bestdeal_list.add(map);
            }
            // }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        /*
         * if(bestdeal_list.isEmpty()){ AlertDialog alertDialog=new
         * AlertDialog.Builder(getParent()).create();
         * alertDialog.setTitle("No Best Deal Found");
         * alertDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
         * {
         * 
         * @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
         * {
         * 
         * 
         * } }); alertDialog.show(); } else{
         */
        /*
         * if (bestdeal_list.isEmpty()) {
         * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty Menu",
         * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); } else{
         */
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        RestaurantDetails.this, bestdeal_list,
                        R.layout.menu_list, new String[] { TAG_MENUNAME,
                                TAG_PRICE }, new int[] { R.id.textView1,
                                R.id.textView3 });
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });
    }
    // }
}
```

All things are working fine but i want to modify my code by dividing the listview into sections. I want first 4 list items under category 1 the other 4 list items under category 2. I dont want expandable listview. Just want to modify above mentioned code.

Comment: You can do this by implementing your custom adapter. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1606642/2410326

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394514/how-to-generate-a-listview-with-headers-above-some-sections

Answer (score 2):

1. `onPostExecute` is being called on the main ("UI") thread so there is really no need to run its code through `runOnUiThread(Runnable)`.
2. If you want to display two types of views in the same `ListView` you will need to modify your `Adapter` to supply it (see `Adapter.getViewTypeCount()`), then you will need to sort your data set (`List` in your example) so it will reflect your requested sort + sections, and finally you will need to handle it in your Adapter (return the appropriate type/view by the given position).
   Also see `Adapter.getItemViewType()` and `Adapter.getView()`.

Comment: can i get that after modifying my above code in post execute.

Comment: a. the `postExecute()` thingy doesn't really related to your core issue
b. you can add sections related objects to your `List` (i.e. add(TitleA), add(DataA1), add(DataA2) ..., add(TitleB), add(DataB1), add(DataB2) ... -> just one of many ways to differentiate your Adapter data-set's inner types)

Answer (score 1):

There are several options for you to chose from. Have a look at the link in one of the comments to your question, or take a look at the [SectionedAdapter](https://github.com/britzl/androidutils/blob/master/src/se/springworks/android/utils/view/SectionedAdapter.java) that I wrote a while back.

What you basically want to do is to use a custom adapter, most likely derived from [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html). You will need to override [getViewTypeCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getViewTypeCount%28%29) and return the number of different kinds of list items that you have in the list. In your case it's 2 since you have normal list items and categories.

You will also have to override [getItemViewType(position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29) and return either a 0 if the item at the specified position is a normal list item or a 1 if it's a category.

Finally you'll also have to override [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) and return a list item of the appropriate type (category or normal list item), based on getItemViewType().

Answer (score 1):

Both britzl and avimak gave good answers but there is another approach that may be simpler and adequate for some use cases.

First specify a list item layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/section_header" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- your layout here ... -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, in your adapter, decide if you want to show the section header or not.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    bindSectionHeader(position, view);
    return view;
}

private void bindSectionHeader(int position, View view) {
    TextView sectionView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.section_header);

    if (isBeginningOfSection(position)) {
        sectionView.setText(getSectionTitle(position));
        sectionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        sectionView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private boolean isBeginningOfSection(int position) {
    // ...
}

private String getSectionTitle(int position) {
    // ...
}
```

An [AlphabetIndexer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AlphabetIndexer.html) may help with implementing the two methods.